# search table for value in column 1 and print data in colum 2 of same row

Tags: python, mysql, bash, awk, sed

I've done my best to find this  -- grep, awk, sed -- I'd like to do this in the linux shell, javaScript or python (or whatever, but I know those 3 best).  The code I am posting is JavaScript (my favorite), but I am willing to take an answer in just about anything -- hell, I'll learn a new language or do it in Scratch if it keeps me from writing a bajillion lines...

I have a list of torque values for a group of gear-units and their corresponding ID number (I'm using round numbers for simplification - torque value on the left and part number on the right):

```
maxTorq:Unit ID#
100:6100
200:6105
300:6110
.......and this goes for HUNDREDS of lines.....
99990:6985
100000:6990
```

My current code is a simple repetition of "if...else if" statements..
HERE it is! (run it, it's not too crappy.. needs more CSS and on my website it has some cool graphics and styling.)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("../media/sumi.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
#main {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto; 
  border: solid;
  background: #87CEEB;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative; 
}
#answer {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto; 
  border: solid;
  background: #FFEFD5;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 300px; 
}
</style>

<body>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sumitomo Sizer</title><br>

</head>
<body>
<h6> here it is:
<h1><b>Sumitomo Cyclo sizer!!</b></h1>
<div id="main">
<P> I am only showing 8 of the 18 available ratios.  Sure, you might need       the others for some reason, but you can do most things with these 8.</p>

<p>  What output speed is closest AND OVER what you need:
  <select id="vara">
<option value="11">159 RPM (11:1)</option>
<option value="17">103 RPM (17:1)</option>
<option value="29">60 RPM (29:1)</option>
<option value="35">50 RPM (35:1)</option>
<option value="43">40 RPM (43:1)</option>
<option value="59">30 RPM (59:1</option>
<option value="71">25 RPM (71:1)</option>
<option value="87">20 RPM (87:1)</option>
</select>
</p>

<P>What is your motor Horsepower @1750:
   <select id="varb">
<option value="0.5">1/2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1.5">1-1/2</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="7.5">7.5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>belt drive ratio: 
<input id="varc" type="text" value="1"/>:1
</p>
<P>Input style:
   <select id="vard">
<option value="0">Standard</option>
<option value="1">Top motor mount</option>
<option value="2">C-face (w/coupling)</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>Click the button to get your Sumitomo size</p>

<button onclick="sumisize()">Find it</button>
</p>
<div id="answer">
Sumitomo part number: <h2><p id="resultd"></h2></p><p id="resulta"></p>
Actual output speed: <p id="resultb"> </p>
Torque in inch-lbs.:<p id="resultc"></p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8">

function sumisize()
{
var y = (document.getElementById('vara').value);
var v = (document.getElementById('varb').value);
var u = (document.getElementById('varc').value);
var q = (document.getElementById('vard').value);
var w=(v*36);
var t=(w*u);
var s=(t*y);
var r=((1750/u)/y);
var x="";
var z=(y);
var p=(q);
var o="";
var n="";
var m="";

if (p>0 && v==0.5)
  {
  m="-56"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==1)
  {
  m="-143"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==1.5)
  {
  m="-145"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==2)
  {
  m="-145"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==3)
  {
  m="-182"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==5)
  {
  m="-184"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==7.5)
  {
  m="-213"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==10)
  {
  m="-215"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==15)
  {
  m="-254"
  }
else if (p>0 && v==20)
  {
  m="-256"
  }
if (p==0)
  {
  o="CHH";
  }
else if (p==1)
  {
  o="CHHP";
  }
else if (p==2 && u==1)
  {
  o="CHHJ";
  }
else 
  {
  n=" Please Set 'Belt Drive Ratio' to 1 ";
  }
if (z==11 && s<=298)
  {
  x="-6080-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=393)
  {
  x="-6085-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=579)
  {
  x="-6090-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=765)
  {
  x="-6095-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=1190)
  {
  x="-6100-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=1610)
  {
  x="-6105-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=1790)
  {
  x="-6110-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=1970)
  {
  x="-6115-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=2560)
  {
  x="-6120-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=2990)
  {
  x="-6125-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=4730)
  {
  x="-6130-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=5700)
  {
  x="-6135-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=6570)
  {
  x="-6140-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=7650)
  {
  x="-6145-Y11";
  }
else if (z==11 && s<=9900)
  {
  x="-6160-Y11";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=408)
  {
  x="-6080-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=536)
  {
  x="-6085-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=788)
  {
  x="-6090-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=1040)
  {
  x="-6095-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=1620)
  {
  x="-6100-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=2190)
  {
  x="-6105-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=2440)
  {
  x="-6110-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=2680)
  {
  x="-6115-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=3490)
  {
  x="-6120-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=4070)
  {
  x="-6125-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17 && s<=5360)
  {
  x="-6130-Y17";
  }
else if (z==17  && s<=6160)
  {
  x="-6135-Y17"
  }
else if (z==17  && s<=8250)
  {
  x="-6140-Y17"
  }
else if (z==17  && s<=9370)
  {
  x="-6145-Y17"
  }
else if (z==17  && s<=10200)
  {
  x="-6160-Y17"
  }
else if (z==17  && s<=14700)
  {
  x="-6165-Y17"
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=621)
  {
  x="-6085-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=832)
  {
  x="-6090-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=1040)
  {
  x="-6095-29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=1610)
  {
  x="-6100-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=2120)
  {
  x="-6105-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=2530)
  {
  x="-6110-29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=2950)
  {
  x="-6115-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=3980)
  {
  x="-6120-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=5010)
  {
  x="-6125-29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=5960)
  {
  x="-6130-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=7500)
  {
  x="-6135-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=7920)
  {
  x="-6140-29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=9980)
  {
  x="-6145-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=14000)
  {
  x="-6160-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=15200)
  {
  x="-6165-29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=19000)
  {
  x="-6170-Y29";
  }
else if (z==29 && s<=25000)
  {
  x="-6175-Y29";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=981)
  {
  x="-6090-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=1220)
  {
  x="-6095-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=1560)
  {
  x="-6100-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=1920)
  {
  x="-6105-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=2410)
  {
  x="-6110-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=2900)
  {
  x="-6115-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=4010)
  {
  x="-6120-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=5100)
  {
  x="-6125-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=5950)
  {
  x="-6130-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=6820)
  {
  x="-6135-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=8360)
  {
  x="-6140-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=12200)
  {
  x="-6145-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=15500)
  {
  x="-6160-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=18300)
  {
  x="-6165-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=19300)
  {
  x="-6170-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=24100)
  {
  x="-6175-Y35";
  }
else if (z==35 && s<=30200)
  {
  x="-6180-Y35";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=858)
  {
  x="-6090-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=1190)
  {
  x="-6095-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=1540)
  {
  x="-6100-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=2140)
  {
  x="-6105-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=2570)
  {
  x="-6110-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=2990)
  {
  x="-6115-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=3780)
  {
  x="-6120-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=4700)
  {
  x="-6125-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=5910)
  {
  x="-6130-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=7430)
  {
  x="-6135-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=7780)
  {
  x="-6140-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=10600)
  {
  x="-6145-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=14700)
  {
  x="-6160-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=15500)
  {
  x="-6165-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=19200)
  {
  x="-6170-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=22300)
  {
  x="-6175-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=29800)
  {
  x="-6180-Y43";
  }
else if (z==43 && s<=37200)
  {
  x="-6185-Y43";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=1010)
  {
  x="-6095-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=1400)
  {
  x="-6100-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=1920)
  {
  x="-6105-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=2330)
  {
  x="-6110-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=2730)
  {
  x="-6115-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=3530)
  {
  x="-6120-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=4380)
  {
  x="-6125-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=5920)
  {
  x="-6130-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=6830)
  {
  x="-6135-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=8010)
  {
  x="-6140-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=9900)
  {
  x="-6145-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=12000)
  {
  x="-6160-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=15500)
  {
  x="-6165-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=19400)
  {
  x="-6170-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=25500)
  {
  x="-6175-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=26400)
  {
  x="-6180-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=32500)
  {
  x="-6185-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=41300)
  {
  x="-6190-Y59";
  }
else if (z==59 && s<=51000)
  {
  x="-6195-Y59";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=1410)
  {
  x="-6100-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=1830)
  {
  x="-6105-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=2180)
  {
  x="-6110-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=2470)
  {
  x="-6115-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=3120)
  {
  x="-6120-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=3910)
  {
  x="-6125-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=5960)
  {
  x="-6130-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=7070)
  {
  x="-6135-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=7920)
  {
  x="-6140-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=9810)
  {
  x="-6145-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=11300)
  {
  x="-6160-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=18400)
  {
  x="-6165-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=19300)
  {
  x="-6170-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=23300)
  {
  x="-6175-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=28600)
  {
  x="-6180-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=31900)
  {
  x="-6185-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=44100)
  {
  x="-6190-Y71";
  }
else if (z==71 && s<=50800)
  {
  x="-6195-Y71";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=1730)
  {
  x="-6100-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=2260)
  {
  x="-6105-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=2640)
  {
  x="-6110-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=3030)
  {
  x="-6115-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=3770)
  {
  x="-6120-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=4510)
  {
  x="-6125-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=5660)
  {
  x="-6130-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=7620)
  {
  x="-6135-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=7900)
  {
  x="-6140-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=9900)
  {
  x="-6145-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=13900)
  {
  x="-6160-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=15500)
  {
  x="-6165-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=19200)
  {
  x="-6170-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=22500)
  {
  x="-6175-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=28500)
  {
  x="-6180-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=34200)
  {
  x="-6185-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=47000)
  {
  x="-6190-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=54400)
  {
  x="-6195-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=63500)
  {
  x="-6205-Y87";
  }
else if (z==87 && s<=85400)
  {
  x="-6215-Y87";
  }
else
  {
  x="- stop and contact Jay at 601.583.2005"
  }
document.getElementById("resulta").innerHTML= o + x + m;
document.getElementById('resultb').innerHTML = Math.round(r) + " RPM";
document.getElementById("resultc").innerHTML= s;
document.getElementById("resultd").innerHTML= n;

}
</script>
Use this application at your own risk. Results are calculated based on the Cyclo 6000 series catalog information.  The information provided is for reference ONLY!! I do not make any claims the information is correct, viable, usable, safe or marketable.  YOU are responsible for insuring YOU select the correct speed reducer based on the literature and guidance of Sumitomo Machinery Corporation of America (or Japan)!

</center>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is great EXCEPT, I have 100 hours invested in that method and I need to do 5-6 MORE manufacturers that will be LARGER than the one I just did.  This is JUST ONE line in one manufacturer and I truncated it to cut the work in half by only proving 8 of the possible 18 ratios they offer...

What I would like to do is create a 2-column table for each gear-line (like example at the beginning) and have the computer look at column #1 to find a value in Column #1 that is GREATER THAN "s" (Row #x, Column #1) but less than "s" in the next row (Row #y, Column #1) and print the data of Row #y column #2.

It just seems like there is a simple answer and I cannot find it -- grep, awk, sed, SOMETHING and I'm missing it....

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input and output. How does the input look, formula and how should the output look?

Comment: Your problem sounds interesting but there's not nearly enough relevant information in your question to be able to help you solve it (e.g. most of the numbers in your code aren't present in your input so is there a mapping between the 2 or not?). Don't just add a whole bunch of complexity to your question though - come up with and post a [mcve] (emphasis on **Minimal**) that truly represents your problem so we can help you.

Comment: One thing you have to learn as a programmer: don't get too attached to a solution. It doesn't matter how many hours you're put into it, if a better solution can be found, throw it out.

Comment: Basically, there has GOT to be an easier way.  Just run the script in your fav browser and see my quandary.....

Answer (score 1):

This is simple in Awk. Pass in the value you want to compare against (you would probably have this in a shell variable, but in this example, I'm hard-coding 203) and get back the second column from the last line where the value was equal to or larger than the number in the first column.

```
awk -F : -v value="203" 'NR==1 { next }  # skip the silly header line
    value >= $1 { m=$2; next }
    { exit }  # done; fall through to END
    END { print m }' file
```

This obviously assumes that the input file is sorted in monotonically increasing order on the first column, as in your example.

`-F :` sets the column separator (the default in Awk is any run of whitespace) and `-v value=whatever` sets the Awk variable `value` to whatever. (A common newbie misunderstanding is assuming that shell variables are available to Awk -- they are not. Awk basically knows nothing about the calling program, and cannot even assume that it is being called from a shell in the first place.)

The main logic should be easy to follow -- Awk reads a line at a time and sets `m` to the second column as long as the value is bigger than or equal to the number of the first column, then skips the rest of the script and proceeds again from the start with the next input line in memory.  When the condition no longer holds, we quit; when the script quits, we print the value we captured from the previous line. (Quitting is a minor optimization here; there is obviously no need to read the rest of the file.) As a couple of corner cases, we skip the first line (because it contains a header, not actual data) and cope with falling off the end of the file by doing the printing from the `END` block rather than just printing and quitting only when we actually encounter a line where the first column is actually larger than the input value.

If you need this in a shell script, the construct to obtain just the output value in a variable is

```
outputvalue=$(awk -F : -v value="$inputvalue" ....)
```

The same logic is obviously also easy to implement in Python.

```
import logging, sys

try:
    value = int(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    logging.error('Syntax: {0} value'.format(sys.argv[0]))
    exit(123)

final = None
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    try:
        first, second = line.split(':')
    except ValueError:
        logging.warn('Invalid input {0}'.format(line))
        continue
    first = int(first)
    if value >= first:
        final = second
    else:
        break
print(final)
```

---

Finally, here is a refactored version of your Javascript code which (I hope) does basically the same thing with much less code. I am not really a JavaScript programmer and I have not attempted to clean up the code too much but I'm guessing something like this is what you *actually* want.

```js
function sumisize()
{
var y = (document.getElementById('vara').value);
var v = (document.getElementById('varb').value);
var u = (document.getElementById('varc').value);
var q = (document.getElementById('vard').value);
var w=(v*36);
var t=(w*u);
var s=(t*y);
var r=((1750/u)/y);
var x="";
var z=(y);
var p=(q);
var o="";
var n="";
var m="";

var zvalues = {
    11: { 298: 6080,   393: 6085,   579: 6090,   765: 6095,  1190: 6100,
  1610: 6105,  1790: 6110,  1970: 6115,  2560: 6120,  2990: 6125,
  4730: 6130,  5700: 6135,  6570: 6140,  7650: 6145,  9900: 6160 },
    17: { 408: 6080,   536: 6085,   788: 6090,  1040: 6095,  1620: 6100,
  2190: 6105,  2440: 6110,  2680: 6115,  3490: 6120,  4070: 6125,
         5360: 6130,  6160: 6135,  8250: 6140,  9370: 6145, 10200: 6160,
 14700: 6165 },
    29: { 621: 6085,   832: 6090,  1040: 6095,  1610: 6100,  2120: 6105,
  2530: 6110,  2950: 6115,  3980: 6120,  5010: 6125,  5960: 6130,
  7500: 6135,  7920: 6140,  9980: 6145, 14000: 6160, 15200: 6165,
 19000: 6170, 25000: 6175 },
    35: { 981: 6090,  1220: 6095,  1560: 6100,  1920: 6105,  2410: 6110,
  2900: 6115,  4010: 6120,  5100: 6125,  5950: 6130,  6820: 6135,
  8360: 6140, 12200: 6145, 15500: 6160, 18300: 6165, 19300: 6170,
 24100: 6175, 30200: 6180 },
    43: { 858: 6090,  1190: 6095,  1540: 6100,  2140: 6105,  2570: 6110,
  2990: 6115,  3780: 6120,  4700: 6125, 5910: 6130,  7430: 6135,
  7780: 6140, 10600: 6145, 14700: 6160, 15500: 6165, 19200: 6170,
 22300: 6175, 29800: 6180, 37200: 6185 },
    59: {1010: 6095,  1400: 6100,  1920: 6105,  2330: 6110,  2730: 6115,
  3530: 6120,  4380: 6125,  5920: 6130,  6830: 6135,  8010: 6140,
  9900: 6145, 12000: 6160, 15500: 6165, 19400: 6170, 25500: 6175,
 26400: 6180, 32500: 6185, 41300: 6190, 51000: 6195 },
    71: {1410: 6100,  1830: 6105,  2180: 6110, 2470: 6115,  3120: 6120,
  3910: 6125,  5960: 6130,  7070: 6135,  7920: 6140,  9810: 6145,
 11300: 6160, 18400: 6165, 19300: 6170, 23300: 6175, 28600: 6180,
 31900: 6185, 44100: 6190, 50800: 6195 },
    87: {1730: 6100,  2260: 6105,  2640: 6110,  3030: 6115,  3770: 6120,
  4510: 6125,  5660: 6130,  7620: 6135,  7900: 6140,  9900: 6145,
 13900: 6160, 15500: 6165, 19200: 6170, 22500: 6175, 28500: 6180,
 34200: 6185, 47000: 6190, 54400: 6195, 63500: 6205, 85400: 6215 }
};

var mvalues = { 0.5:  -56,  1.0: -143,  1.5: -145,  2.0: -145,  3.0: -182,
  5.0: -184,  7.5: -213, 10.0: -215, 15.0: -254, 20.0: -256 };

if (p>0) {
    m=mvalues[v];
}

if (p==0)
  {
  o="CHH";
  }
else if (p==1)
  {
  o="CHHP";
  }
else if (p==2 && u==1)
  {
  o="CHHJ";
  }
else 
  {
  n=" Please Set 'Belt Drive Ratio' to 1 ";
  }
 
    var smax = -1;
    var diag = "diagnostics: "
    for (var k in zvalues[z]) {
 diag += "k(" + k + ")<=s(" + s + ")? "
 if (k<=s && k>smax) {
     diag += "k>smax(" + smax + "); dv=" + zvalues[z][k] + ". "
       smax = k;
       dv = zvalues[z][k];
   }
    }
    diag += " Final smax = " + smax
    if (smax > -1)
    {
 x="-" + dv + "-Y" + z;
    }
else
  {
  x="- stop and contact Jay at 601.583.2005" + diag
  }
document.getElementById("resulta").innerHTML= o + x + m;
document.getElementById('resultb').innerHTML = Math.round(r) + " RPM";
document.getElementById("resultc").innerHTML= s;
document.getElementById("resultd").innerHTML= n;

}
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("../media/sumi.jpeg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right top;
}
#main {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto; 
  border: solid;
  background: #87CEEB;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative; 
}
/*
#answer {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto; 
  border: solid;
  background: #FFEFD5;
  padding: 50px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 300px; 
}*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sumitomo Sizer</title><br>
</head>
<body>
<h6> here it is:
<h1><b>Sumitomo Cyclo sizer!!</b></h1>
<div id="main">
<P> I am only showing 8 of the 18 available ratios.  Sure, you might need       the others for some reason, but you can do most things with these 8.</p>

<p>  What output speed is closest AND OVER what you need:
  <select id="vara">
<option value="11">159 RPM (11:1)</option>
<option value="17">103 RPM (17:1)</option>
<option value="29">60 RPM (29:1)</option>
<option value="35">50 RPM (35:1)</option>
<option value="43">40 RPM (43:1)</option>
<option value="59">30 RPM (59:1</option>
<option value="71">25 RPM (71:1)</option>
<option value="87">20 RPM (87:1)</option>
</select>
</p>

<P>What is your motor Horsepower @1750:
   <select id="varb">
<option value="0.5">1/2</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="1.5">1-1/2</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="7.5">7.5</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>belt drive ratio: 
<input id="varc" type="text" value="1"/>:1
</p>
<P>Input style:
   <select id="vard">
<option value="0">Standard</option>
<option value="1">Top motor mount</option>
<option value="2">C-face (w/coupling)</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>Click the button to get your Sumitomo size</p>

<button onclick="sumisize()">Find it</button>
</p>
<div id="answer">
Sumitomo part number: <h2><p id="resultd"></h2></p><p id="resulta"></p>
Actual output speed: <p id="resultb"> </p>
Torque in inch-lbs.:<p id="resultc"></p>
</div>

Use this application at your own risk. Results are calculated based on the Cyclo 6000 series catalog information.  The information provided is for reference ONLY!! I do not make any claims the information is correct, viable, usable, safe or marketable.  YOU are responsible for insuring YOU select the correct speed reducer based on the literature and guidance of Sumitomo Machinery Corporation of America (or Japan)!

</center>
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: when looking at the python version, how does python know where my "table" is located?  sorry, I'm really weak with Python, but I have done some raspberrry pi controls with Python, so, I am willing to dig a little deeper into it.. it would be my best option if I cannot do this in JavaScript..

Comment: Just like the Awk script, this Python script is reading the table from standard input (`sys.stdin`). You'd run this like `python script 230 <file` to use the table in `file` and a value of 230.

Comment: Updated with a Javascript version now.

Answer (score 0):

I REALLY can't tell from your question what the best approach would be to whatever the problem is you're trying to solve but a better way to write the series of if-else's you've posted might be (in awk):

```
split("298 393 579 765 1190 1610",nums)
for (i=1; i in nums; i++) {
    if (s < nums[i]) {
        x = "-" (6075 + i*5) "-Y" z
        break
    }
}
```

That's just to give you an idea of one different way your code could be written more briefly but without more info in your question even that might be unnecessarily lengthy or you may need to do something else with `z` if all `z` values doing have the same `s` comparisons or `x` outputs.

Comment: that looks great, but it's far above my level of expertise...   I'm not opposed to using code I don't comprehend, but  I have to be able to "fit it." I posted my WHOLE code.. somehow I think it can be simplified...  You're answer may work, but, I don't "get it"...

Comment: This code hinges on the assumption that the second column is completely regular, and can be calculated from the first.  It's absolutely a better approach if the assumption is correct.

Comment: @triplee, no it's awk. Oh I see, you mean the OPs code. Yeah, looks like it so idk why that's not tagged. Johnny - I doubt if anyones going to read your whole code trying to figure it out. I'm certainly not. If you want help with a problem it's up to you to come up with a [mcve] that demonstrates the specific problem you want help with, not throw up 1000 lines of code that has your problem hidden in it like a needle in a haystack. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: Oh, I should have recognized who was posting this (-: ... Without the usual Awk decorations I doubt the OP could have figured out which language this is (I couldn't either!); maybe clarify?

Comment: Done. Yeah, until he posted his massive code sample I thought what he had posted was already awk but I also thought my code was going to be temporary until he provided more info.... Oh well, thanks for the suggestion, you're right of course.

Comment: If the left column is completely regular but the right one isn't, you could calculate the exact key (int (n/5)*5) and then use it as an index into an associative array (aka dictionary in Javascript).

Comment: Sorry, but yes, I posted this "massive coda," as I was asked to post the code (originally only had a small snippet of 40-50 lines)...  BTW, it's HTML, so you can just run it in a browser and see what I'm trying to do.  MY CODE works, but it is rather cumbersome to type in - even "cut and past" is a LOOONNNGGG process.. and the next ones I want to do are LONGER, so you can see why I am here asking for help.

Comment: No-one asked you to post your full code, you were asked to post a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem. Note **Minimal**. See [ask] if it's not clear what it takes to ask a question in this forum but basically - the more you expect us to do (and the more time you expect us to spend) to understand your problem, the less chance of anyone taking the time to do so so it's entirely in your best interests to put your own time into coming up with a [mcve] that demonstrates JUST the specific problem at hand.

Comment: the left column is a mechanical value that is the maximum that the gearbox can produce.  the right column is a "part number" assigned by the manufacturer..  I can calculate a "torque value that I need, but I want the computer the select the gearbox by "part number."   I just want a find a value in the left column and print the value of the 2nd column in the SAME ROW

Comment: or, sorry, misunderstood what the first comment was saying? Should I take it all down? forgive me, I am just hack who was looking for some help on a problem I have had fro quite a while.. sorry for the inconvenience.  I'll try to figure it out on my own (my code works, so it's good enough)- I've been quite successful so far.. never should have walked into the world of real programmers/coders.

Comment: We're happy to help, but if you have 5,000 lines of if-else statements to handle 10,000 lines of input, then just reduce it to, say, 5 lines of if-else statements and 10 lines of input so we have something we can understand in seconds rather than hours. I'd expect it to be very easy for you to come up with a [mcve] and I'm sure you'd get a great answer you'd be very happy with if you did.

Comment: Looking at the Javascript code, the column values are not at all regular like in the (too simple) faux example data. The first series of digits in the second column is pretty regular, but even there, there are overlaps and gaps (6200 is missing) and the part after Y adds another dimension. Going forward, I suppose model numbers from a different manufacturer which completely break these patterns could appear. So, good observation but from a poor example, apparently.